# Empty submitted Formspree form

Tags: html, forms, email

I have a question in regards to Formspree. Everything is working, I can submit the form and I receive an e-mail to my mailbox each time the form is submitted, but in the e-mails I received there is nothing, no content, no message, no name, no e-mail of person.

It looks like this:

Hey there,
Someone just submitted your form on ...... Here's what they had to say:

This form was submitted at 12:31 PM UTC - 02 July 2017.

Maybe someone has an idea why it's not working properly? The HTML code looks like this (apart from the e-mail):

```
<form method="POST" action="http://formspree.io/e-mail">
    <div id="formular" class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
        <br>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Your mail">
        <br>
        <textarea placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    </div>                  
    <div id="send" class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-color hvr-wobble-vertical" value="Send message">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: All your form fields are missing a `name` attribute. No name means no value will be send when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `name` attribute in your `input field`

Change your input field like this

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name">
 <input type="email" placeholder="Your mail" name="_replyto">
```

Comment: This is exactly the issue. Forgot to add it to one field on a site where we use Formspree, this fixed it. I used the same name for both the `id` and `name` attributes.